# How can I prevent this from running on my screen reader when input is empty?

Tags: vue.js, wai-aria

I'm learning about vue and aria, i have an input where you can write names and it will expand a list with certain number of people. I want my screenreader don't show the people based on the lenght, i want make it so when you delete all the letters the screenreader reads ' '
I have this line
   `<span class="sr-only" v-if:"filterCities.length > 0" :aria-label=" 'Showing '+filterCities.length + ' results'"></span>`

I'm sure i'm not doing it right with the v-if: since VS CODE says 'v-if directives require no modifer, require that attribute value. What does it exactly mean?
can someone help me please?

Comment: it should be `v-if=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `v-if="filterCities.length > 0"` with an equal.

```
   <span class="sr-only" v-if="filterCities.length > 0" :aria-label=" 'Showing '+filterCities.length + ' results'"></span>
```